# Why the variable currentValue is never 100?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The variable 'i' in the loop inside the IEnumerator ProcessImages method get to value 99 I added a public int variable currentFrameIndex to see the counting of 'i' and it's getting to 99 I added a screenshot at the bottom.

but the radial progress bar image it's getting to 100%
and since 'i' is 99 and never 100 so the variable currentValue is also never get to 100 so the flag bool imagesLoaded is never true.

I could put the flag in the end of the Coroutine but that won't make it to get to 100 in the loop.

Why it's not getting to 100 ? Since 'i' start from 0 and there are 100 file it's getting to 99 but why then the radial image show 100% ? And what should I change so it will get to 100 so the flag imagesLoaded will be true ? Or maybe I should change it instead :

```
if (currentValue < 100)
```

To

```
if (currentValue < fileInfos.Length - 1)
```

This is the script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class StreamVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D[] frames;                // array of textures
    public float framesPerSecond = 2.0f;    // delay between frames
    public RawImage image;
    public int currentFrameIndex;
    public GameObject LoadingText;
    public Text ProgressIndicator;
    public Image LoadingBar;
    public float speed;

    private float currentValue;
    private FileInfo[] info;
    private bool imagesLoaded = false;

    void Start()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\tmp");
        // since you use ToLower() the capitalized version are quite redundant btw ;)
        string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
        info = dir.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();

        if (!image)
        {
            image = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
        }

        StartCoroutine(ProcessImages(info));

        foreach (var frame in frames)
            frame.Apply(true, true);

    }

    public IEnumerator ProcessImages(FileInfo[] fileInfos)
    {
        var output = new Texture2D[fileInfos.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < fileInfos.Length; i++)
        {
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfos[i].FullName);
            output[i] = new Texture2D(1, 1);
            if (!ImageConversion.LoadImage((Texture2D)output[i], bytes, false))
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError($"Could not load image from {fileInfos.Length}!", this);
            }

            if (currentValue < 100)
            {
                currentValue = 100 * (i + 1) / fileInfos.Length;
                ProgressIndicator.text = ((int)currentValue).ToString() + "%";
                LoadingText.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                LoadingText.SetActive(false);
                ProgressIndicator.text = "Done";

                imagesLoaded = true;
            }

            LoadingBar.fillAmount = currentValue / 100;

            currentFrameIndex = i;

            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private Texture2D[] GetTextures(FileInfo[] fileInfos)
    {
        var output = new Texture2D[fileInfos.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < fileInfos.Length; i++)
        {
            var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfos[i].FullName);
            output[i] = new Texture2D(1, 1);
            if (!ImageConversion.LoadImage((Texture2D)output[i], bytes, false))
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError($"Could not load image from {fileInfos.Length}!", this);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (imagesLoaded == true)
        {
            int index = (int)(Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;
            image.texture = frames[index];
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        foreach (var frame in frames)
            Destroy(frame);
    }
}
```

[image: Radial image percentages is 100% but 'i' and the currentFrameIndex are 99]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since 'i' start from 0 and there are 100 file it's getting to 99 but why then the radial image show 100% ?* 
That's because `100 * (99 + 1) / 100 = 100.`

I think you can get rid of that if statement and just have:

```
public IEnumerator ProcessImages(FileInfo[] fileInfos)
{
    var output = new Texture2D[fileInfos.Length];
    LoadingText.SetActive(true);

    for (var i = 0; i < fileInfos.Length; i++)
    {
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileInfos[i].FullName);
        output[i] = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        if (!ImageConversion.LoadImage((Texture2D)output[i], bytes, false))
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError($"Could not load image from {fileInfos.Length}!", this);
        }
        
        currentValue = 100 * (i + 1) / fileInfos.Length;
        ProgressIndicator.text = ((int)currentValue).ToString() + "%";            

        LoadingBar.fillAmount = currentValue / 100;

        currentFrameIndex = i;

        yield return null;
    }

    LoadingText.SetActive(false);
    ProgressIndicator.text = "Done";

    imagesLoaded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the length is 100 and i should be < 100 it will stop at 99.
use <= to get to 100 BUT (!!)
remmeber that a 100 size array will start at 0 and ends in 99, there is nothing in the 100 position....